# php script cause 100% cpu by mysql

Tags: php, mysql, cpu-usage

I have a php script that create a csv file.

When I run it server is always with 100% cpu usage and I can't access to website for 4/5 minutes.

How can I limit cpu usage for this script?

In the script there are a mysql SELECT with about 30000 result row and some strip_tags.

Thank you in advance

A small part of code:

```
       $listing_sql = "
   SELECT
   p.products_id,
   p.products_image,
   p.manufacturers_id, 
p.products_details_original_supplier_code,
p.products_details_original_prod_code,
   p.products_weight,
   p.products_tax_class_id AS tax_id,
p.products_quantity_local AS availability,
   pd.products_name,
   g.customers_group_price,
   pd.products_description,
   p2c.categories_id,
   c.parent_id,
   c.categories_id,
   cd.categories_name,
   m.manufacturers_id,
   g.customers_group_price,
   g.products_id,
   IF(p.manufacturers_id = 0, NULL, m.manufacturers_name) AS marca,
   IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) AS specials_new_products_price,
   IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, g.customers_group_price) AS final_price,
   IF(p.products_model = NULL, -1, p.products_model) as codprod
   FROM
   ".TABLE_PRODUCTS." p
   LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_SPECIALS." s ON p.products_id = s.products_id
   LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_MANUFACTURERS." m ON p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id
   LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PRODUCTS_GROUPS." g ON p.products_id = g.products_id AND g.customers_group_id = 3,
   ".TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION." pd,
   ".TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES." p2c, 
   ".TABLE_CATEGORIES." c,
   ".TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION." cd

   WHERE
   p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id AND
   c.categories_id = cd.categories_id AND
   p.products_id = p2c.products_id AND
   pd.products_id = p2c.products_id AND
   pd.language_id = '$language_id' AND 
   cd.language_id = '$language_id'
   ORDER BY final_price DESC
   ";
```

...

```
$filestring.=$row["products_id"]."|".$row["products_name"]."|".$site_url."/images/".$row["products_image"]."|".$site_url."/product_info.php?products_id=".$row["products_id"]."|".$cat_list."|".$final_price."|".$descrizione1."|".$row["marca"]."|" . $row["availability"] ."|" . $shippingprice2 ."|" . $row["codprod"]."|".$row["products_details_original_supplier_code"]."|".$row["products_details_original_prod_code"]."<endrecord>\r\n";


     $rescount += 1;// $rescount++;
  }  
//      echo $filestring;

$filename = $file."name_file";
file_put_contents("./files/$filename.csv", "$filestring");
exit;
```

.

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `namedb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `oscpro_categories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oscpro_categories` (
  `on_header` int(1) default '0',
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `categories_image` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `sort_order` int(3) default NULL,
  `date_added` datetime default NULL,
  `last_modified` datetime default NULL,
  `categories_import_module_codes` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `categories_status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `categories_allowed_customers_gid` int(11) default '0',
  `categories_image_top` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `categories_oscproie_module_code` varchar(255) default 'OSCPROIE',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`categories_id`),
  KEY `idx_categories_parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1748 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `oscpro_categories_description`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oscpro_categories_description` (
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `categories_name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `categories_description` text,
  `categories_pages_descriptionmetatag` text,
  `categories_pages_keywordsmetatag` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `categories_pages_titletag` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `categories_image_alttag` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `categories_pages_htmlseocode` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`categories_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `idx_categories_name` (`categories_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `oscpro_manufacturers`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oscpro_manufacturers` (
  `manufacturers_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `manufacturers_name` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `manufacturers_image` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `date_added` datetime default NULL,
  `last_modified` datetime default NULL,
  `manufacturers_import_module_codes` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `manufacturers_oscproie_module_code` varchar(255) default 'OSCPROIE',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`manufacturers_id`),
  KEY `IDX_MANUFACTURERS_NAME` (`manufacturers_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=610 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `oscpro_products`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oscpro_products` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `products_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `products_details_original_supplier_code` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `products_image_hot_linking_big` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_hot_linking_medium` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_hot_linking_small` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_extra1` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_extra2` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_extra3` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_extra4` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_extra5` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_extra6` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000',
  `products_date_added` datetime default NULL,
  `products_last_modified` datetime default NULL,
  `products_date_available` datetime default NULL,
  `products_weight` decimal(15,3) NOT NULL default '0.000',
  `products_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `products_carrot` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `products_tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `manufacturers_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `products_ordered` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `products_percentage` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `products_details_original_prod_code` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `products_model` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `products_details_pages_numbers` int(12) default '0',
  `products_details_isbn` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_upc` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `products_details_release_date` datetime default NULL,
  `products_details_run_time` int(12) default NULL,
  `products_import_module_codes` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_outside_code` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_image_hot_linking` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `products_to_rss` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
  `products_master` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `products_master_status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '-1',
  `products_master_type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `products_listing_status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '1',
  `products_master_temp` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_ship_price` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_ship_flag` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `products_quantity_local` int(11) default '0',
  `products_quantity_remote` int(11) default '0',
  `products_details_oscproie_code` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_oscproie_module_code` varchar(255) default 'OSCPROIE',
  `products_bundle` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL default 'no',
  `sold_in_bundle_only` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL default 'no',
  `icecatcode` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `eancode` varchar(13) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`),
  KEY `idx_products_date_added` (`products_date_added`),
  KEY `idx_products_model` (`products_details_original_supplier_code`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=39294 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `oscpro_products_description`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oscpro_products_description` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `products_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `products_description` text,
  `products_url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_extra1` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_extra1_title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_extra2` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_extra2_title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_extra3` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_extra3_title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_extra4` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_url_extra4_title` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_viewed` int(5) default '0',
  `products_details_author` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_label` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_distributedby` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_levels` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_language` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_format` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `main_image_alt_tag` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_generic3` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_titletag` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_keywordsmetatag` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `products_details_descriptionmetatag` text,
  `products_details_hot_linking` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `products_name` (`products_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=39294 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `oscpro_products_groups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oscpro_products_groups` (
  `customers_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `customers_group_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000',
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `products_price` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `oscpro_products_to_categories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oscpro_products_to_categories` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`,`categories_id`),
  KEY `ptc_catidx` (`categories_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `oscpro_specials`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oscpro_specials` (
  `specials_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `specials_new_products_price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL default '0.0000',
  `specials_date_added` datetime default NULL,
  `specials_last_modified` datetime default NULL,
  `expires_date` datetime default NULL,
  `date_status_change` datetime default NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `customers_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`specials_id`),
  KEY `idx_specials_products_id` (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=303 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: If you run the query alone without creating the CSV file, do you still reach 100% CPU usage?

Comment: Please give us some more clarity

Comment: @user1415571 Yes, also without creating file, is the same.

Comment: @sailesh just add a part of script

Comment: You will simply have to optimise this. A lot. Your query is too complex. Maybe you can make it more efficient, maybe you can break it down into several smaller operations, maybe you need to change the way you store your data, maybe you need to think about pre-computation and caching. There is no easy answer here.

Comment: Invest in a better CPU

Comment: @deceze ok thank you, but script work fine, I have file ready in about 5 minutes. Problem is that, in this five minutes, mysql run 100% of cpu and site in not accessible. I need only to set low priority to this script, so I have file ready in 15 minutes but with 30% of cpu usage

Comment: @halfer table structure is very complex. I use oscommerce, run on mysql 5.0.91 MyISAM. I have a dedicate server with xeon E3110

Comment: @dwhite.me I don't think, maybe I can run this script in 1 minutes with better cpu, but in those minute the problem will be the same

Comment: "table structure is very complex" - let's see it, then. I bet your site is locked because you are running this in a web process (and your Apache processing module locks when a script is running). To fix this, move the long-running process to a cron or a job queue.

Comment: @halfer do you mean all db or only those required in the script?

Answer (score 1):

Some initial thoughts on optimisation:

```
p2c.categories_id = c.categories_id AND
c.categories_id = cd.categories_id AND
p.products_id = p2c.products_id AND
pd.products_id = p2c.products_id
```

These looks like they are old-style joins. Since they are full joins, I'd start off with switching them to `INNER JOIN` types. I don't know if it will make a performance benefit, but it does tell the database that it is a join and not a general equality comparison, and thus it may be able to make an on-the-fly optimisation.

```
AND
pd.language_id = '$language_id' AND 
cd.language_id = '$language_id'
```

You don't seem to have indexes on these columns, so start with these, and measure your query performance again.

Then examine your join columns, and try adding indexes on those too. Keep an accurate log of what indexes you add: don't just create an index on everything, as it may hurt `INSERT` performance elsewhere. I would add an index, measure performance change, delete it, add another, measure performance change, and then maybe try two together, etc.

Don't forget to look at [your explain plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html), to see where the bottleneck is.

Your version of MySQL is also very old, can you update it?

---

Also, consider tackling the problem another way. As I mentioned in the comments, Apache locks whilst this long process is running; my guess is that this is the reason for the site not being operational in the meantime, and is not to do with CPU load at all. The site may run more slowly for other users, but should not lock up entirely.

Thus, set up a cron to run this query and store the results outside of your web process, and your site should remain operational whilst it runs. Try it - it is easy enough to set up!

---

A third thing to try: your tables are MyISAM, which I believe lock at the table level rather than at the row level. Thus, copy your data to a test machine and set up your site, and confirm that whilst your script is running in this non-live environment it is inaccessible. Then, [convert your tables to InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html), and see if the problem persists. InnoDB locks at a row level, and so may permit access even while other rows are busy with your long-running query.

Another way to confirm this might be to create a trivial PHP script and MySQL table, such that the script reads/writes to the table. It should still work when your long-running script is active, and if it does, it will show that MySQL is still responding to requests fine, but that any queries **involving the locked tables** will have to wait.

Comment: I tried INNER JOIN with not benefit. I want to use SELECT EXPLAIN but I don't know how. I can try to update mysql but I'm scared for errors. There is no way to simply set , for this script, to use max 30% of cpu / mysql resource?

Comment: thank you for all but I still have this script run on cronjob how I need it, every 3 hours, but the problem is the same.

Comment: @Fabio: to be clear, you have moved this long-running query from a web process to a cron script, and you find that your web process is still non-responsive for the duration of the query, the time for which is around five minutes?

Comment: yes, I have cronjob >wget URL --delete-after and time to run is about five minutes.

Comment: Ah, the `wget` is your problem, @Fabio. You are still running it in an Apache process (the wget fetches it via HTTP, like a browser would). Modify it so it runs on the console, and use `php script.php` to run it.

Comment: I tried direct from console and the problem is the same also with use php namefile.php

Comment: @Fabio: can you try a trivial web page (e.g. `phpinfo()`), to make absolutely sure it is Apache locking whilst your script is running? It should still work fine, and if it does, it might be table-level locking -- see my new edit.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Do you mean to create a webpage without any call to database? Just simply html? I know that isn't Apache the problem but mysql. When I run script Apache work fine about 10/20% of cpu, mysql take other cpu.

Comment: @Fabio, no, it would be better to be a PHP page (with no database access), to ensure the Apache engine runs it in the same way. Please just try it, it will take you two minutes. If that does work fine, then try my new idea.

Comment: I tried to open another php page and it work fine. I tried also to open, when script run, another site in the same machine, and it work fine. Just the site of same databse doesn't work. Why? If cpu work 100% it should be for all site ...

Comment: or maybe there is a way to duplicate database and use new one to run script? And how I can update it before run script?

Comment: Sounds complicated. Please try setting it up a local copy of this first, converted to InnoDB. Then test it.